# Fidelity for initial state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

fidelity for pure state with respect to t=0 is 1. My teacher told me this.

But I am not getting this.

This is my detailed question

the initial state(t=0)$|\psi\rangle=|\alpha\rangle|0\rangle$

the final state (t) $|\chi\rangle= |cos(t)\alpha\rangle|i\alpha\sin(t)\rangle$

Fidelity between the states I got is $e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{-|\alpha\sin(t)|^2}e^{-|\alpha\cos(t)|^2}$

when I tried to find fidelity for t=0, I got answer as 0.00004. But my teacher said that fidelity should be 1 here. I don't know how?

Comment: You're right: Fidelity is defined for two density operators: $F=F(\rho,\sigma)$. Have you read the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states)? If so, what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: I am by no means an expert. Can you provide a source where the concept of 'Fidelity for initial state' is defined? If yes, include it in the question. I think what could make sense is to define $\tilde{F}(\rho) \equiv F(\rho, |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|)$ which for all states $\rho$ gives you the fidelity with respect to the 'initial state' (what ever this means) $|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$.

Comment: So you ask about the definition of a concept you have defined?!

Comment: No. I just want to know whether both my question 1 and its answer is right or wrong?

Comment: @jakob I have edited the question. Maybe it is now somewhat understandable

Comment: The problem is that you have not defined what you mean with 'fidelity for initial state" or 'fidelity for pure state at $t=0$'. The equation $|\psi\rangle \langle \psi| =1$ makes so sense, as on the RHS there is a $c$-number, while on the LHS there is an operator on the Hilbert space.

Comment: @jakob sorry this |ψ⟩⟨ψ| is wrong. Instead it should be a inner product of |ψ⟩ and let us assume the initial state to be |α⟩|0⟩. Then applying fidelity formula F=|⟨α|α⟩⟨0|0⟩|. So F=1.

Comment: You've made a mistake. The *t* =0 limit of χ is not  ψ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Actually I had made a mistake in the order of ket. (Thanks to the forum for pointing that out). So when

Initial state ($t=0$) = $|\psi\rangle=|\alpha\rangle|0\rangle$

Final state=$|\chi\rangle= |\cos(t)\alpha\rangle|i\alpha\sin(t)\rangle$

I will get fidelity as
$$F=e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{-|\alpha\cos(t)|^2}|e^{|\alpha|^2cos(t)}|^2 e^{-|\alpha\sin(t)|^2}$$

I can further simplify it as
$$=e^{-|\alpha|^2} e^{-|\alpha\cos(t)|^2}e^{|\alpha|^2cos(t)}e^{|\alpha|^2cos(t)}e^{-|\alpha\sin(t)|^2}$$

$$ =e^{-|\alpha|^2} e^{-|\alpha|^2cos^2(t)}e^{2|\alpha|^2cos(t)} e^{-|\alpha\sin(t)|^2}$$

Now if I substitute $t=0$, I am getting $F=1$.